# Geometry nodes: how to move selected faces along their individual normals

Tags: geometry-nodes

Modelling manually in Edit Mode, if I select some faces and want to move them along their respective normals, I can just change the pivot point to Individual Origins and the transform orientation to Normal, and then move. How can I do the same thing in geonodes? I seem to get stuck because, even if I capture Normals and Index on the face domain, Set Position always interpolates to work on vertices.

[image]

On the left is the base mesh, center is the desired result modelling manually, and right is my failed geonodes attempt

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture your normal only for the faces to be moved, then the domain interpolation face→vertex wouldn't be affected by faces with $<0, 0, 0>$ value - other than scaling down the vector, since $\left|{x + 0 + 0 + 0 \over 4}\right| < |x|$

[image]

[image]